# route constraints in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say we have an constraint like:

```
{qty:int:max(10)?}
```

I think the "?" mean optional, but what does this constraint mean? does it mean that max of 10 is optional? if yes so wahts the difference between it and

```
{qty:int}
```

Comment: The `?` applies to the entire constraint, not the `max` part.

Comment: @DavidG  so it means that the parameter  will match any strings and only <= 10 if it is an number?

Comment: It mean the parameter must either be absent or an integer with a maximum value of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding about `?` is correct (its optional).

Now the `max(10)` means that the integer value of `qty` can not be greater than 10.

For example lets have route as `[Route(“users/{qty:int:max(10)?}”)]`

Example urls:

```
/users/1  //correct as `1` is less than `10`

/users    //correct because of the Optional modifier `?`

/users/11 //not correct as `11` is greater than `max(10)` constraint.
```

Comment: Your example route [Route(“users/{qty:int:max(10)}”)] doesn't have '?'. Is it a typo mistake?